# GET Rows WITH MIN(Date) on different column values

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I would like to ask a question about a query which i find difficult to be done, at least for me. I need the rows of the table below (marked with red rectangles), which are having the `min(date)` while the table have different user `id`'s, `quiz id`'s.

If anyone can help me with this, i would be happy!

Thanks in advance!

[Here](http://grtest.hu/_stackoverflow/question.jpg) is a picture from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this sql. This sql will help in case of you are having multiple users having multiple exams.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/085864/7)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test(
userid int,
enddate datetime,
quizid int);

insert into test
values(823,'2013-02-06 14:23:05',5);

insert into test
values(823,'2013-02-06 14:23:05',5);

insert into test
values(823,'2013-02-06 14:23:05',5);


insert into test
values(824,'2013-02-06 14:23:08',5);


insert into test
values(824,'2013-02-06 14:23:10',5);
```

**Query 1**:

```
 select DISTINCT userid,quizid,enddate
    from test
    where enddate IN(
    select min(enddate)
    from test
    group by userId,quizId
    )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/085864/7/0)**:

```
| USERID | QUIZID |                         ENDDATE |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    823 |      5 | February, 06 2013 14:23:05+0000 |
|    824 |      5 | February, 06 2013 14:23:08+0000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select t1.* from sometable t1
    where t1.EndDate = (select min(t2.EndDate) from sometable t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do simple query like:

```
select * from your_table_name where EndDate = (select min(EndDate) from your_table_name)
```